# Read input file with backslash (\) delimiter c++

Tags: c++, stringtokenizer, boost-tokenizer

My input file is like this:

```
C:\Users\DeadCoder\AppData\Local\CoCreate
```

I am making a tree and I need to abstract the names of directories while reading from input file with `\` delimiter. Like in the above example, i need to abstract separately  c:, users, DeadCoder, Appdata .... I hope every one understands the questions.
Now Let us see the options that we got.

`1-`    `istringstream` works perfectly fine for `whitespace` but not for `\`.

`2-` `strtok()` works on char. So I would have to change my string to char and I really don't want to do this.

`3-  Boost Tokenizer()` This one seems interesting and I don't have any familiarity with it in the past except I just googled it a while ago. I copied the code and it is like this:

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
using namespace boost;

int main(){

    string tempStr;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("input.txt");
    int i=0;

    while (!fin.eof()){
        getline(fin,tempStr);
        char_separator<char> sep("\"); // error: missing terminating " character
        tokenizer<char_separator<char>> tokens(tempStr, sep);
        for (const auto& t : tokens) {
            cout << t << "." << endl;
        }
}
```

Now this gives the error that  `"error: boost/foreach.hpp: No such file or directory"`
 can Someone help me here. And Is there any other `better way` to read the input file with `\ delimiter`. Please don't use extensive codes like `class tokenizer()` as I am still learning c++.

EDIT: I didn't have boost library installed therefore I was having this error. it would be much of favor if someone can explain a better way to `tokenize` string without installing a third library.

Best;
DeadCoder.

Comment: Have you installed `Boost` library ?

Comment: Nope. Isn't it by default there.

Comment: It's a third party library. Download it from http://www.boost.org/

Comment: Okay fine. Is there any other way to do this task, I mean I don't have to add any third library.

Comment: There is a way. you can use c_str() function on string. but you want to avoid it. don't know why .

Comment: Yes. Read the line from the file. Tokenize the string based on the delimeter. Store the tokens in std::vector<std::string>. For reference see this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c

Comment: @Arpit This would change my string to char right. and then I can  tokenize it easily.?????????

Comment: yep it is.http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

Comment: Getting in here because I think I see where this is going. You **cannot** use `strok()` on the result of `c_str()`. `c_str()` returns a `const char *` (meaning you aren't allowed to change it at all), and `strtok()` manipulates the string in place.

Comment: @BoBTFish I have not tried it so can't say but \\ delimiter does work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ (and other language based on C) the `\` character in a string or character literal is the *escape* character. It means it *escapes* the next character in the literal. This is so you can have, for example, a `"` inside a string at all. To have a `\` inside a string literal you need to escape the backslash by having two of them: `"\\"`.

You can read more about the valid escape sequences in C++ e.g. [in this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).

---

As for the problem with Boost, you need to tell the compiler where you installed it. This is done in the project properties of your IDE.

---

If you want to tokenize *without* using a third-party library such as Boost, there are a couple of ways. One way could be to use [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). Another fo use the [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) functions of the standard `string` class.

Comment: Okay it worked but I really need to know why I have to use two \\ . Because you are not making sense to me in the above statement.

Comment: @DeadCoder You know how to write a literal newline inside a string? You use `"\n"` right? This is the same as using `"\\"` to mean a single backslash. A backslash inside a character or string _literal_ is telling the compiler that the next character is a special character that means something else.

Comment: @DeadCoder You have to use two \\ because that's the way the language is defined.

Comment: @JamesKanze and Joachmin ...Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Any sort of generalized tokenizer here would be overkill.  Just use
`std::find( s.begin(), s.end(), '\\' )` to find each separator,
and the two iterator constructor of `std::string` to put it into
a separate string.  (Your compiler treats the first `\` as an
escape character.)  Something like:

```
std::vector<std::string> fields;
std::string::const_iterator end = s.end();
std::string::const_iterator current = s.begin();
std::string::const_iterator next
        = std::find( current, end, '\\' ):
while ( next != end ) {
    fields.push_back( std::string( current, next ) );
    current = next + 1;
    next = std::find( current, end, '\\' );
}
fields.push_back( std::string( current, next ) );
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
char_separator<char> sep("\") 
                          ^^^ You need to escape the \ . use "\\"
```

the `\` is used to indicate a escape sequence. But `to escape that escape, you need other escape`

Use this : `char_separator<char> sep("\\")`

To install the boost lib: [Install Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html)

Other choice:

```
getline(fin,tempStr);
char *cstr=new char[tempStr.length()+1];
strcpy(cstr,tempStr.c_str())

//... Now you can use strtok() on cstr
```